# How to connect Liferay with Mysql Database

Tags: database, liferay

I am new in Liferay. I want to connect Liferay with MySQL database. I am using Liferay CE (Version? - came bundled with tomcat (6.0.29)). Please tell me the steps for this. Thank you

Comment: Also, for interests sake, the name is "Liferay" (all one word, only the L is capitalized) and not, life-ray ;)

Comment: Corrected name spelling in the question. For completeness sake you might want to edit the actual Liferay version number - I don't have all versions here, but you gave the tomcat version number, not Liferay's.

Answer (score 8):

To build upon what has already been mentioned already, edit the file portal-ext.properties found in liferay-portal-xxx/tomcat-xxx/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes (if it doesn't exist already then create it).

Add these lines to it:

```
jdbc.default.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.default.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/lportal?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useFastDateParsing=false
jdbc.default.username=<insert your mysql username>
jdbc.default.password=<insert your mysql password>
```

It also might be worth creating the lportal table in mysql.

```
mysql -u root -p <<< "create database lportal character set utf8;"
```

Download and extract the [Liferay database scripts](http://www.liferay.com/downloads/liferay-portal/additional-files) found here.  Then run one, e.g.

```
mysql -u root -p < /path-to-the-script/create-mysql.sql
```

More information can be found in this [Liferay Ubuntu Installation Guide](http://www.liferay.com/web/guest/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Development%20Environment%20%28Ubuntu%20Linux%29) (be weary as it's for an version but the database section is useful) and this [Liferay Database Configuration Guide](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Database+Configuration).

Comment: added "character set utf8" to the create database instruction - this is a quite important instruction when you're on a platform that does not default to that by itself.

Answer (score 2):

Paste the following line of code in portal-ext.properties:

```
jdbc.default.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.default.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/lportal?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useFastDateParsing=false
jdbc.default.username=
jdbc.default.password=
```

Comment: To follow along with Amresh's answer, here is a link to the Wiki http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Database+Configuration

Comment: Sir i already do this. portal-ext.properties file not exit then i create the new file with this name but not connect the mysql.thanks for your answer

Comment: If you're on windows, make sure that Explorer doesn't hide the real extension. You might have created portal-ext.properties.txt

Answer (score 0):

1. Download Liferay CE
2. Install MySQL and create a database
3. Unzip liferay and create file if no exist portal.properties into liferay_home/tomcat-6.0.29/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/clases
4. Paste this:

jdbc.default.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

jdbc.default.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/nameDatabase?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useFastDateParsing=false

jdbc.default.username=name

jdbc.default.password=password

Run onm Eclipse, or Windows .bat/Linux .sh
i hope works for you

Answer (score 0):

```
    1)path--->home/karthik/Desktop/LiferaySetup/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes---->create an empty doc with name as portal-ext.properties
    paste the below code:
    jdbc.default.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    jdbc.default.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/lportal?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useFastDateParsing=false
    jdbc.default.username=root
    jdbc.default.password=root
    2)path--->/home/karthik/Desktop/LiferaySetup/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/conf/Catalina/localhost-->Enter the below code inside ROOT.xml
     <Context path="" crossContext="true">

        <!-- JAAS -->

        <!--<Realm
            className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm"
            appName="PortalRealm"
            userClassNames="com.liferay.portal.kernel.security.jaas.PortalPrincipal"
            roleClassNames="com.liferay.portal.kernel.security.jaas.PortalRole"
        />-->

        <!--
        Uncomment the following to disable persistent sessions across reboots.
        -->

        <!--<Manager pathname="" />-->

        <!--
        Uncomment the following to not use sessions. See the property
        "session.disabled" in portal.properties.
        -->

        <!--<Manager className="com.liferay.support.tomcat.session.SessionLessManagerBase" />-->
    <Resource
        name="jdbc/LiferayPool"
        auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/lportal?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"
        username="root"
        password="root"
        maxActive="20"
    />

    </Context>
If you follow the above 2 statements you can create easily
```